# get variable from infinite loop in .net socket

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sockets

I'm using .NET synchronous socket to send data from a client to server.

I need to get the data from the `StartListening()` method to use it in the `Main()` but 
the variable data is inside an infinite loop `( while(true))`.
Any help please?

This is the server code :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;


public class SynchronousSocketListener
{

    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo;
    IPAddress ipAddress ;
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint;

    Socket listener;
   // Incoming data from the client.
    public static string data = null;

    // Volatile is used as hint to the compiler that this data
    // member will be accessed by multiple threads.
    private volatile bool _shouldStop;

    public  void InitializeListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
        // host running the application.
         ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
         ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
         localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11007);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("please stop!");
        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try {
                sender.Connect(localEndPoint);
                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
                // Release the socket.
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            } 
    }

    public  void StartListening()
    {
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
        // listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {

            // Start listening for connections.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // Thread is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();

                // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                if (_shouldStop)
                {
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                    break;
                }
                data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Show the data on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

                // Echo the data back to the client.
                //byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Salam !");
                handler.Send(msg);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am the Synchronous Socket Server\n");
        SynchronousSocketListener pServer = new SynchronousSocketListener();
        pServer.InitializeListening();
        Thread serverkerThread = new Thread(pServer.StartListening);
        serverkerThread.Start();
        // Loop until server thread activates.
        while (!serverkerThread.IsAlive) ;

        Console.WriteLine("listening thread sevice started...\n");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress Q when you want to quit...\n");
        int car;
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            car = Console.Read();
            if (car == 81)
            {
                // Request that the worker thread stop itself:
                pServer.StopListening();

                // Use the Join method to block the current process 
                // until the object's thread terminates.
                serverkerThread.Join();
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        Console.WriteLine("listening thread sevice stopped and program will be exited...\n");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As your member `data` is static you can access it from anywhere in your class.

Comment: Just two things I would like to know: Why are you using synchronous sockets (as blocking sockets are generally easier and more efficient to use), and *when* do you expect to read the value (as reading from sockets is an asynchronous operation)?

Answer (score 0):

The received data (given it is an ASCII-string ending with "EOF") is stored in the public member named "data" of your pServer object, you can access it like this:

```
    Thread serverkerThread = new Thread(pServer.StartListening);
    serverkerThread.Start();
    // Loop until server thread activates.
    while (!serverkerThread.IsAlive) ;

    string receivedString = pServer.data; // <<--- here we get the received string

    Console.WriteLine("listening thread sevice started...\n");
```

Comment: string receivedString = pServer.data; is not working.
receivedString is empty because it contains the value of the member data before going inside the while loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I did not understand your code properly. Then, your SynchronousSocketListener should somehow inform the caller that it have completed receiving its data. You might use events for that: define an event in your SynchronousSocketListener class and subscribe on it in your Main method. You will need some synchronization though, as your Main method and your delegate will work in different threads.